# ¿Cómo mostrar y ocultar una contraseña en un JPasswordField?

Tags: java

desearía saber cómo hacer para al presionar un botón el JPasswordField muestre  la contraseña y al hacer otra vez click lo oculte con una caracter especial. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Donnie, bienvenido a SO en español. Te sugiero que veas el [tour] y [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas. ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta agregando lo que has investigado/probado?

Answer (score 2):

Es simple creas una variable char `i` y almacenas el EchoChar del PasswordField con `getEchoChar()` y agregas este código al evento del botón

```
if (a) {  // a es una variable boolean en true
    jPasswordField.setEchoChar((char)0); // este método es el que hace visible el texto del jPasswordField
    a = false;
} else {
    jPasswordField.setEchoChar(i); // i es el char
    a = true;
}
```

Comment: y para ocultarlo de nuevo que debo hacer